# Size of byte array gets double when it retrieve from Postgres database

Tags: java, postgresql, jetty

I am using JSF2.0, jetty server and Postgres database. I want to store mp3 file in database in byte array formet. I upload the byte array of mp3 file. But when I retrive same byte array from database I get byte array of double size and my because of that my mp3 file is not working as well.

```
public void updateAnnouncementDetail(AnnouncementDetail announcementDetail) {
    System.out.println("Upload  byte array size:" + announcementDetail.getContent().length);
    Session sess=get Session();
    sess.beginTransaction();
    sess.save(announcementDetail);
    sess.getTransaction().commit();
    AnnouncementDetail detail;
    detail = retrieveAnnouncementDetailById(new AnnouncementDetailPK(announcementDetail.getAnnouncementDetailPK().getAnnouncement(), announcementDetail.getAnnouncementDetailPK().getLanguage()));
    System.out.println("Retrived byte array size:" + detail.getContent().length);
}
```

**Output:**

Upload  byte array size:384440

Retrived byte array size:768879

I dont know why it is happening. I am storing byte array and on the next line I am retriving it. But I get byte array of double size. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: What's a `Session`? Is this Hibernate? If so, you should say so in the question title and tags, as that's quite important, and we'll need to see the mappings.

Comment: Also, you need to show us the SQL used to create the tables you're working with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with binary data in Postgres, it is important to use proper data binding.

First, data column must be of type `BYTEA`. Is that the case?

To store data, use prepared statements and be sure to call **`setBinaryStream()`**:

```
File file = new File("myimage.gif");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO images VALUES (?, ?)"
);
ps.setString(1, file.getName());
ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int)file.length());
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
fis.close();
```

To retrieve data, also use prepared statements and use **`getBytes()`**:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT img FROM images WHERE imgname = ?"
);
ps.setString(1, "myimage.gif");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    byte[] imgBytes = rs.getBytes(1);
    // use the data in some way here
}
rs.close();
ps.close();
```

See more [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/binary-data.html).

Answer (score 10):

Postgres 9.x bytea values have hex as default output. So, try:

`ALTER DATABASE database_name SET bytea_output = 'escape';`

Comment: If this does not work check if you're not using an outdated jdbc driver.